# AJAX, json, knockout and search engine crawl

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, web-crawler

I am considering using ajax requests to pull content dynamically into a page and then binding that content up to the DOM using knockout.

Is there a way to load content dynamically into a page that makes the page look like it's content is being rendered by the server as normal get request?

If not, do most search engines read dynamic content today? For example, if one were to use an ajax call to fill in the title tag of a page - do most modern search engines support that crawl?

Comment: yes if you use any template engine, you can send your data to the template engine.  Look at this for the next question https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2358775/seo-strategies-for-javascript-heavy-single-page-applications-or-ajax-sites

Comment: Is this true today? It's two years old. Google has changed it's stance in the last year on ajax crawling.: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started